# How to fix the horizontal Scroll bar position on CGRIDVIEW YII?

Tags: php, sorting, yii, scrollbar, cgridview

I am using CGRIDVIEW

suppose there are 20 columns in the gridview so the horizintal scroll bar will come in to the picture

if i want to sort the 20th column i have to scrolbar to reach there

When i sort that column the gridview is reloaded,

so the Horizontal scrollbar loses its position and comes to the original position

how to make scrolbar at the 20th column only after sorting the gridview

Here is the GridView -->

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
            'type' => 'bordered striped',
            'id' => 'bike_search_grid',   
            'dataProvider' => $model->search_bike(),
            'ajaxUpdate' => true, //false if you want to reload aentire page (useful if sorting has an effect to other widgets)
            'filter' => null, 
            'template'=>'<div style="overflow:auto;">{items}</div>{pager}{summary}',
            'columns' => $selected_columns,
            'enablePagination' => true
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [beforeAjaxUpdate](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#beforeAjaxUpdate-detail) to get current scroll position, and [afterAjaxUpdate](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#afterAjaxUpdate-detail) to set it after updating table:

```
 array(
    ...
    'beforeAjaxUpdate'=>'function(){
        position = $("#gridId table").position().left;
    }',
    'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'function(){
        $("#gridId").scrollLeft(position*(-1));
    }',
    ...
 )
```

Comment: Sorry to say, ,,, but this solution does not give me desired result ... more help is appreciated !

Comment: @user3134101 which id of grid do you use (instead of `gridId`)?

Comment: @user3134101 try to use this approach:
 
`'beforeAjaxUpdate'=>'function(id){  
   scroll = $("#"+id).scrollLeft();  
}',  
   'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'function(id){  
   $("#"+id).scrollLeft(scroll);  
}',`

Comment: @user3134101 what about my last advice? Does it work?